# cms page with download function for customers

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, download

I want to make a cms page or just a page where people can download a word document i hope i can make the page so that people can first read what the file is for and then download the specific word document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place a link to the document, and make sure the file has the proper permissions.

With css you can make your link look like a button if that is what you want, for instance I just copied this css from default magento 1.9:

```
.button {
  background: #39c;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Raleway","Helvetica Neue",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And then your link:

```
<a href="path/to/your/file.doc" class="button">Download</a>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Download Button]

Comment: but isnt there a way to place a download button

Comment: Yes you can achieve this using the existing magento styles.

Comment: what is the best place to place the file

Comment: You could put this in many places (phtml, cms pages, etc), since you mention a cms page that could be a good place to do it.